# laravel 5.8 verification email contains ID how to obfuscated it and verify it after click

Tags: security, obfuscation, laravel-5.8

I have a project that is made using Laravel 5.8.

I'm so surprised that Laravel verification link contains the raw id of the user given that this framework have a great decent amount of security !

Can someone give me the steps on how to change the ID (50) in this generated url /email/verify/50?expires=1680922977&signature=19e... ? 50 to something that can be encrypted/decrypted only on serve-side.

and i'm talking about from changing it to verify it.

Comment: IDs aren't a security issue. The signature ensures no one can change the ID, because it uses a secret value not available to the browser or end user (the `APP_KEY`). Your StackOverflow user ID is 3012958. Mine is 1902010. See? Not a problem.

Comment: but when you are the last registered it can give a number (if no deletes) of the total users no ?

Comment: If the number of users in your application needs to be secret, use UUIDs for the user ID. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys